# Mongodb C# Spatial Query

Tags: c#, mongodb, geospatial, mongodb-.net-driver

I'm using the csharpdriver on a Windows 7 machine.

In summary the data structure:

```
public class Site
{
    [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<SiteLocation> Locations = new List<SiteLocation>();
}

public class SiteLocation
{
    [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public List<string> Address { get; set; }
    public GeoJsonPoint<GeoJson2DGeographicCoordinates> Location { get; set; }
}
```

the code to create the index:

```
Database.GetCollection<Site>("site")
  .EnsureIndex(IndexKeys<SiteLocation>.GeoSpatialSpherical(x => x.Location));
```

The query to find points near:

```
var point = GeoJson.Point(GeoJson.Geographic(153.0, -27.5)); //long, lat
var locationClause = Query<SiteLocation>.Near(p => p.Location, point, 2000);
var query = _ctx.Sites.AsQueryable().Where(x => locationClause.Inject());
var results = query.ToList();
```

Unfortunately results returns a count of zero. And there is a record with the same lat,long and others very close.

Any ideas where the problem is?